# Download files from a sharepoint document library that has exceeded the listview threshold

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to download all documents from a SharePoint library that has more than 200K documents and has obviously exceeded the listview threshold and I haven't been able to find a script that will allow me to download these files. Is there a way to download all of these files using Powershell to a file share?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script :

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
cls

$fileName = "File_Downloading_Report"
#'yyyyMMddhhmm   yyyyMMdd
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
#$filename =  $enddate + '_VMReport.doc'  
$logFileName = $fileName +"_"+ $enddate+"_Log.txt"   
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value  
$directoryPath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path  

$directoryPathForLog=$directoryPath+"\"+"LogFiles"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForLog))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForLog
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }  


#$logPath = $directoryPath + "\" + $logFileName 

$logPath = $directoryPathForLog + "\" + $logFileName 

$isLogFileCreated = $False 

#DLL location

$directoryPathForDLL=$directoryPath+"\"+"Dependency Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForDLL))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForDLL
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        } 

#DLL location
$clientDLL=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
$clientDLLRuntime=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path $clientDLL
Add-Type -Path $clientDLLRuntime
#File Download location

$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation=$directoryPath+"\"+"Downloaded Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        } 

#File Download location



function Write-Log([string]$logMsg)  
{   
    if(!$isLogFileCreated){   
        Write-Host "Creating Log File..."   
        if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPath))  
        {  
            Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   
        else   
        {   
            $script:isLogFileCreated = $True   
            Write-Host "Log File ($logFileName) Created..."   
            [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
            Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
        }   
    }   
    else   
    {   
        [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
    }   
} 



#The below function will download the file from SharePoint Online library.
Function FileDownLoadFromSPOnlineLibrary()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SPOSiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SourceFilePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $TargetFilePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $UserName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Password
    )

    Try 
    {      

        $securePassword= $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force  
        #Setup the Context
        $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SPOSiteURL)
        $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $securePassword)

        #Downloading the file from SharePoint online document libray.
        $fileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($ctx,$SourceFilePath)
        $writeStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($TargetFilePath,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
        $fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($writeStream)
        $writeStream.Close()

        Write-host -f Green "File '$SourceFilePath' has been downloaded to '$TargetFilePath' successfully!"
    }
    Catch 
    {

            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +"in Downloading File!: " +$SourceFilePath
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
            Write-Log $ErrorMessage 

    }
}


#Parameters value
$siteURL="https://globalsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/"
$listName="Documents" #Document library name
$fromDate="2019-10-28"
$toDate="2019-11-09"
$downloadLocation=$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation;
$userName = "YourSPOAccount@YourTenantDomain.com"
$password = "YourPassWord"
$securePassword= $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
#$batchSize =1000
#Parameters ends here.


#Setup the Context
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $securePassword)

#Get the List
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$emptyString = ""
#Define CAML Query to get Files from the list in batches
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery

#Here in the below two line "T13:35:58Z" and "T13:36:34Z" are hard coded static value - because while we construct this camel query thru the camel query builder these values gets appended to the date value, so we need this.
$startDateVar=$fromDate+"T13:35:58Z"  
$endDateVar=$toDate+"T13:36:34Z"
#Here in the below two line "T13:35:58Z" and "T13:36:34Z" are hard coded static value - ends here.
#RecursiveAll


$Query.ViewXml = "@
    <View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
        <Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$startDateVar</Value>
         </Geq>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$endDateVar</Value>
         </Leq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>        
    </View>"


$count =0
#Get List Items in Batches
Do
{


    $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
    $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $ListItems.Count

    #Update Postion of the ListItemCollectionPosition
    $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition

    If ($ListItems.Count -eq 0) 
    { 
    Break
    }

    $downloadItemCount=1;

    #Extract the each list item from the List Items collection.
    ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
    {                  
          #Example to Item metadata - this can be used if we want to download based on some item metadata condition.
          #$documentStatus=$Item["documentStatusColumnName"]

            try
            {

                $Ctx.Load($Item.File)
                $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                #$eTagVal=$Item.File.ETag                                         

                #https://globalsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/Shared%20Documents/LegalDoc.docx        
                $SourceFile=$Item.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
                #$TargetFile="C:\PowerShell\DownLoadFilesFromSPOnline\Downloaded Files\LegalDoc.docx" 
                $TargetFile=$downloadLocation+"\"+$Item.File.Name; 

                #If we want to download the specific file type we can check the file type using the below code 
                #if($SourceFile.Contains(".zip")){}

                #Calling the function "FileDownLoadFromSPOnlineLibrary"to download file
                FileDownLoadFromSPOnlineLibrary -SPOSiteURL $SiteURL -SourceFilePath $SourceFile -TargetFilePath $TargetFile -UserName $UserName -Password $Password

                $fileDownloadingMessage=$downloadItemCount.ToString()+": "+$Item.File.Name; 
                Write-Host $fileDownloadingMessage -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
                Write-Log $fileDownloadingMessage

        $downloadItemCount++

        }
        catch
        { 
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +"in: " +$Item.File.Name
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
            Write-Log $ErrorMessage 

        }

    }
    Write-Host "============================================================="
    Write-Host $count
    Write-Host "============================================================="

}While ($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

Source :

[SharePoint Online Automation – O365 – Download files from a document library using PowerShell CSOM](https://www.google.com/amp/s/global-sharepoint.com/powershell/download-file-from-sharepoint-online-document-library-using-powershell-csom/amp/)